# Special character conversion Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

I've got a question.
How may I import special characters? I need to import data to sqlServer, this data contains Chinese and Japanese characters. What query should I make in the Informatica to handle this case? Because in the target table I see that all the special characters are broken.
For example, in sqlServer it's enough to write an insert like: insert into TableName values(**N**'specialCharacter'). But in Informatica how may do this?

I try to modify different code pages, and now I broke all environment. Now it doesn't work for code page incompatibility.

Comment: Infa should be able to handle it if your integration service is running in unicode mode. Any Chinese char should be loaded nicely if its a table target and db is rinning in unicode mode.

Comment: You may test Nstring or Ntext data types in the mapping if the String or Text data types don't work, depending on the target fields data types. You can also check the Connection Object Code Page. See documentation https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/designer-guide/appendix-a--datatype-reference/transformation-data-types/string-data-types.html

Comment: @MickaëlBucas In the targhet table, my data was varchar, i change them to nvarchar, also I change the data in source qualifier from string to nstring, but the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I'v got other tables in my db with correct special characters. I also tried manualy insert some special charactes with N'character', so the destination db it's ok. But the data loaded using informatica aren't correct

Comment: You should verify that the Source Code Page is correct for your source data file. If using Linux, you can check the contents with the command `file`. Some editors can also detect encoding. If it's UTF-8, use it for the Source Code Page, the Target Code Page, and make sure that the Integration Service is running in Unicode mode (as Koushik Roy already said). See doc https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/administrator-guide/understanding-globalization/code-page-compatibility.html